# How to add existing screen to Sketchflow map?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, expression-blend, sketchflow

If I remove a screen from the Map, but still have its xaml files and whatnot, how can I get it back on the map? This seems like it should be pretty straight forward, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

All I seem to be able to do is create a new screen on the map, then cut the xaml from the existing file, paste it in the new one, then delete the original. Then you have to rename the files. That is an enormous hassle.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Right click the screen/file in the project panel and select the make into screen option. (I can't recall the exact terms used on the menu).

Comment: Just found them, thanx to your reply! There're two options `Make Into SketchFlow Screen` and `Make Into SketchFlow Component Screen`